# Drupal: create hierarchical menus from taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there any way to automatically create hierachical menus from taxonomy vocabulary in Drupal ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu).